# Appending Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array, with a potentially unknown amount of arrays within it. Which will currently looks like this:

```
    0 => array:11 [▼
    "PFW" => "123499888"
    "techName" => "Brion Ballard"
    "fiberHood" => "Canton"
    "customer" => "Brion"
    "streetAddress" => "1234 Street"
    "city" => "Canton"
    "state" => "Ms"
    "createdDate" => "04-29-2021"
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "serviceName.1" => "Data Plan Charge"
      "serviceRate.1" => 500.0
      "serviceQuantity.1" => "2"
      "id" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "serviceName.4" => "Technician Hourly Charge"
      "serviceRate.4" => 70.0
      "serviceQuantity.4" => "6"
      "id" => 4
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▼
      "serviceName.6" => "Additional Outlet Installation"
      "serviceRate.6" => 100.0
      "serviceQuantity.6" => "1"
      "id" => 6
    ]
  ]
```

I am really struggling to append or add to the root array. I am currently merging this:

```
     $formedTicket = array(
                'PFW' => $ticket_PFW,
                'techName' => $ticket_Tech,
                'fiberHood' => $ticket_fiber_hood,
                'customer' => $ticket_customer,
                'streetAddress' => $ticket_street_address,
                'city' => $ticket_city,
                'state' => $ticket_state,
                'createdDate' => $ticket_created_on,
            );
```

with the following array(s):

```
                $formedServiceArray = array(
                        'serviceName.' . $id =>  $serviceName, 
                        'serviceRate.' . $id => $serviceRate, 
                        'serviceQuantity.' . $id => $serviceQuantity,
                        'id' => $id,
                    );
```

I have been able to merge once, but I can't seem to continuously append the $formedTicket array. My end structure would be something like this:

```
  $arr = [
          "PFW" => "123499888"
          "techName" => "Brion Ballard"
          "fiberHood" => "Canton"
          "customer" => "Brion"
          "streetAddress" => "1234 Street"
          "city" => "Canton"
          "state" => "Ms"
          "createdDate" => "04-29-2021"
          "serviceName.1" => "Data Plan Charge"
          "serviceRate.1" => 500.0
          "serviceQuantity.1" => "2"
          "id" => 1
          "serviceName.4" => "Technician Hourly Charge"
          "serviceRate.4" => 70.0
          "serviceQuantity.4" => "6"
          "id" => 4
          "serviceName.6" => "Additional Outlet Installation"
          "serviceRate.6" => 100.0
          "serviceQuantity.6" => "1"
          "id" => 6
        ]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried, array_push, array_merge, array_merge_recursive, & array_fill, but may have been using them incorrectly.

Comment: Do you need to have it in that particular structure? I think you could store all the `$formedServiceArray` in a key of the main array. Something like: `['services' => [/** your arrays **/]]`. Then, to add values to it just: `$formedTicket['services'][] = $serviceToAdd;`

Comment: If the above kinda solve your question, let me know to expand on it adding an example as  an answer.

Comment: That was fast! Thanks for responding. No, it doesn't necessarily have to be structured the way I have it set. I will try this out and post my results here shortly.

Comment: Kenny Horna's answer ultimately got me to a solution that I am happy with. I will try to post the full solution this week/weekend.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it.